# SPA design with AngularJS - sharing state across some, but not all, pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

How would you implement something like this in Angular:

I have a multi-page user interaction that shares state across pages/controllers.  Page A launches a multi-page process across pages B, C, and D.  I need to share state across pages B-C-D but as soon as the user goes back to page A (either at completion, or abandoning halfway through) the shared B-C-D state should go away.

I could put the shared state in a service and that would take care of sharing across pages.  But then it's a global singleton for the whole application.  Is there a way to ensure the service is disposed if the transaction is abandoned or completed?

In the server-side, Java EE world this was called "conversation scope" - I'm wondering what the equivalent might be in Knockout or Angular.

Or there a better way to approach the design?  Should I use nested controllers?

Comment: Could you add some more details over why you think a service wouldn't suit your needs ?

Comment: A service would *work* but its lifespan is broader than I need.

Comment: It might not be what you want but why not just go back to basics and use cookies if you want to control lifespan ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty broad question and is going to certainly elicit some opinion based responses. That said, one of the things you can rely on is that services (and factories) are singletons. What that means is if you need to share data between controllers, or across the life of a SPA you can create a service to hold and share that data. That service and its data will exist as long as the page isn't re-loaded.

The basic pattern for a shared data factory is like this is:

```
// define the shared data service
app.factory("SharedData", function () {
  return {
    // just one data object for the purposes of the example
    sharedDataObject: {}
  };
});
```

Once you have defined the service you can define a controller that uses the service something like:

```
app.controller("FirstController", function ($scope, SharedData) {
  $scope.localData = SharedData.sharedDataObject;
});
```

Because we have defined the shared data as an *object* and not as a value - binding to "localData" will allow us to set values that can then be retrieved for as long as the page isn't changed. I put together [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7jaKyQhOd4BXTNjhuE0?p=preview) that shows sharing data between two controllers **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7jaKyQhOd4BXTNjhuE0?p=preview)**. This pattern works just as well if the controllers were on separate views.

Again - I'm not sure if this is the *recommended* pattern but it is one I have seen around and it works pretty well. Best of luck!

---

**NOTE** - This answer is referenced in your question - so it probably isn't exactly what you are looking for. That said, I am posting for others that may need a simple method of saving state on an SPA.

Comment: Yes, this would work.  My question is whether there is a better way when your state is not truly global, but only needed by a subset of pages - is there a way to limit the scope of sharedDataObject to that cluster of pages?

Comment: @wrschneider99 I guess I was proposing that this method + the idea that the service could listen to the "$locationChangeStart" and "$locationChangeSuccess" would be enough to write what you are looking for. Besides services, factories and global variables (shudder) I haven't seen any particularly great ways of maintaining state. Just my two cents!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the shared state into a service, just add a reset() function to it that gets called when they go to the "A" step or when they complete the process.

And I think you could do it with a nested controller too. You'd probably still need to add a reset() function for handling all the cases.